# When using coroutines, why can't network work be done on the main thread? (Android)

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines

I understand that a coroutine does not block a thread and can delegate the thread to another coroutine while it is doing its work.

I'm wondering why I shouldn't do network work in a coroutine with Dispatcher.Main.

While doing network work, you will be able to perform other UI-related tasks without blocking the Main Thread.

What I was thinking is, even if you can give up the work to another coroutine, network work can take a long time, and as a result, is it because the main thread has a lot of UI-related work to do, which wastes resources?

```kotlin
// works well
lifecycleScope.launch {
            repeatOnLifecycle(Lifecycle.State.STARTED) {
                val service = RetrofitClient.buildService(GithubApiService::class.java)
                val response = service.getIssues("JakeWharton", "hugo")
                Log.d("TAG", " - response: $response")
            }
        }

@GET("/repos/{user}/{repo}/issues")
    suspend fun getIssues(
        @Path("user") user: String,
        @Path("repo") repo: String
    ): List<Issue>
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear and therefore you got much different answers. But if I understood you correctly and you ask why we are not allowed to perform network operations while we are in the `Dispatchers.Main` coroutine context, then... well, we actually can do this. As long as the network operation is a suspending function as in your example, there's nothing wrong with it. We can't perform a **blocking** network operation in this context.

Comment: Even in the context of coroutines, the actual I/O itself will block. If you block the main thread then it cannot do anything, let alone process other coroutines. But it's okay to call a _suspending_ function (from the main thread) that will perform I/O because, if implemented correctly, said function will switch to a different dispatcher (e.g., `Dispatchers.IO`). Suspending a coroutine on the main thread is okay, as the main thread remains free to do other work. Blocking the main thread, however, is not okay.

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with using `Dispatchers.Main` to call your `getIssues` suspend function. It doesn't matter what dispatcher you are using to call `suspend` functions, because `suspend` functions do not block (unless you incorrectly defined the suspend function yourself by putting blocking code in it). You only have to avoid calling *blocking* functions on the main thread.

If you defined a *blocking* network function, it would freeze your app if you called it on the main thread.

Comment: Are you sure about that?  A coroutine would suspend and allow another coroutine to run on the thread.  But that wouldn't return control to the main thread's looper, which is inside the coroutine that calls onCreate.  So onCreate would not return, the looper would not be called, and you'd get an ANR.  So a suspending coroutine would be just as bad as a blocking one, you'd need to launch() it.

Comment: Isn't `Dispatchers.Main` single-threaded? If data layer's method does not change coroutine context, method will be suspend but what context and thread will be used to download something?

Comment: @Steyrix If a suspend function didn't change the context and performs blocking I/O directly, then this is a faulty implemented function as suspend functions are disallowed to block the caller thread.

Comment: @GabeSechan This is the main point of coroutines, isn't it? That we can wait in-line without blocking the caller thread. Tenfour04 is correct. As a rule of thumb we shouldn't switch the thread when calling a suspend function, because it is responsibility of the function, not the caller, to choose the correct thread. We shouldn't even have to know how it is implemented internally and if it needs switching or not.

Comment: @GabeSechan Or maybe I misunderstood you a little. Of course we can't call a suspend function in `onCreate` directly and we have to `launch` it, because we can't call suspend functions from non-suspend ones. But I don't really see how this is related to the above answer. Here we call a suspend function from a suspending context.

Comment: @GabeSechan, I’m quite sure. Not sure what kind of situation you’re talking about. If you launch a long-running coroutine from `onCreate()`, the first suspend function call in that coroutine will relinquish control of the main thread and allow `onCreate()` to return. Are you talking about trying to call the network suspend function using `runBlocking`? That of course would create the situation you describe but is not what the OP’s code is doing.

Comment: @Sterix, the suspend function you defined in your interface is turned into an implemented function by Retrofit (assuming that is the library you are using). When you call the suspend function, Retrofit is doing the blocking work on some thread in its own thread pool. It is probably using `suspendCancellableCoroutine` to implement this in a suspending way. This function allows you to suspend a coroutine, do something in some other thread having nothing to do with Kotlin dispatchers, and then resume from suspension when done.

Comment: @Tenfour04 No, suspending won't allow onCreate to return.  It will allow the main thread to move to another coroutine.  But in the android framework, you have a message loop that is constantly taking a message from a queue and running it.  That message queue read is part of the coroutine that just got suspended, so it would not process additional messages.

Comment: @GabeSechan, what you’re saying sounds completely wrong to me but maybe I’m misunderstanding you. The coroutine is broken up into multiple messages. Each time it reaches code in the context of Dispatchers.Main it will submit a new message to the main looper and that message will run to completion, which will be at the next context switch in the coroutine (the next suspend function that doesn’t use Dispatchers.Main).

Comment: If you call `lifecycleScope.launch { delay(5000L); Log.i(TAG, "Coroutine finishing" }` in onCreate and then log something in onStart, you’ll see that everything on the main lifecycle continues to run fine while the coroutine is running in parallel.

Comment: If coroutines locked up onCreate  and other lifecycle functions they are called from, it would be impossible to safely use them with UI ever.

Comment: @GabeSechan You somehow assumes if we start a coroutine, then the "starting" thread has to wait for it. This is a behavior of `runBlocking()` only, which is discouraged and not used here. If we do `lifecycleScope.launch` then it launches coroutines using the Android main looper. `Dispatchers.Main` uses the main looper underneath, so whenever it needs to resume a coroutine, it schedules it to the main looper. Then when suspending, it frees the thread for the looper.

Answer (score 1):

Main reason that network call can't be done on Main Thread, that it block the thread, and Main thread is the only one mustn't be blocked.

On the code above you provide, it can work because it's Retrofit's internal mechanism, network call will be dispatched to
background thread if you mark retrofit function with suspend.

If you make pure network call with pure `URL` and `HTTPConnection`, It will be blocked. And cause app crash with `NetworkOnMainThreadException`

Here is example code of why you should not call network on Main Thread:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContent {
            TestAppTheme {
                val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

                Column(Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                    horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                    verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center
                ) {
                    CircularProgressIndicator(
                        Modifier
                            .size(50.dp),
                        strokeWidth = 2.dp,
                        color = Color.Black
                    )
                    Spacer(Modifier.height(40.dp))
                    Button(onClick = {
                        scope.launch {
                            makeNetworkCall()
                        }
                    }) {
                        Text(text = "Call")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

suspend fun makeNetworkCall() {
    val url = URL("https://www.google.com")
    val connection = (url.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection)
    connection.requestMethod = "GET"
    val wr = DataOutputStream(
        connection.outputStream
    )
    wr.close()

    val inputStream = connection.inputStream
    val rd = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(inputStream))
    println(rd)
}
```

Comment: Somehow I find your answer most clear for me, but I would suggest you to remove code example since it is not much related to the question itself

Answer (score 0):

Why you shouldn't?  There's a few reasons.  The first is it would still likely crash.  The strict mode policy enforcer doesn't know about coroutines.  It's just going to check the thread that it's running on, and throw an exception if it's the main thread.  It isn't smart enough to do anything else.  And given that it needs to support Java which doesn't have coroutines, it would be difficult to make it smarter.

Another is how coroutines and the Android framework interact. Suspending allows another coroutine to run.  But allowing another coroutine to run wouldn't allow other lifecycle functions to run (you need to finish your onCreate first).  The looper that handles all the messages to send things to the main thread wouldn't be returned to (because onCreate didn't finish), so it wouldn't be able to process the next message.  Now if you launch the coroutine all of that is avoided.  But you couldn't run it in place.

A minor reason would be because you'd confuse the OS's scheduler.  The scheduler tends to classify threads as IO or computational, trying to give longer time blocks to computation and shorter but more immediate ones to IO.  Run your IO on the same thread as your main and the scheduler will get confused and run much less optimally.  So even if you could run it on one thread it would be best not to.

Comment: What about the network call itself? Will it be executed if suspending happens? If `Dispatchers.Main` is single-threaded and the network call does not switch context to `IO`, what thread and context will be used to execute the network call?

Answer (score 0):

simply because the main tread(UI thread) is responsible for displaying the ui of the screen so if you put too much work on it at the same time it can lead to your app being laggy and irresponsible  .

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

Coroutines can be used in the main thread for network calls, but network calls may take more time because of multiple reasons, and for that time the main thread is blocked.
Because the main thread is responsible for rendering the UI, it will give a bad user experience as well as it may result in ANR  (Application Not Responding).